# NSUserDefaults NSMutable Array Not Saving Between Sessions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, synchronization, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

I have an NSMutableArray stored in NSUserDefaults.  The mutable array is properly edited and the results of the edit can be viewed with:

`NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]);`

However, when I quit and relaunch the application, the user defaults are back to their original form.

I try to save state by running this method to force synchronization:

```
-(void) saveUserDefaults{
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]){
    NSLog(@"Defaults saved");
}else{
    NSLog(@"Defaults save failed");
}

NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]);
```

}

Are there any ideas why this might not be saving?

I set the user default arrays using this code the first time the application is run:

```
// Check if first time run
if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"isFirstRun"] isEqualToString:@"no"]) {

    // Not first run, NSUserDefault arrays are already set
}else {
    // First Run of Program 
    // Mark for future
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"no" forKey:@"isFirstRun"];


    designerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"Alberta Ferretti", @"Alberto Fermani", @"Alejandro Ingelmo", @"Alexander McQueen", @"Alexander Wang", @"Ann Demeulemeester", @"Anne Klein", @"Aquatalia", @"Anya Hindmarch", @"Ash", @"Badgley Mischka Platinum Label", @"Balenciaga ", @"BCBGMAXAZRIA", @"BC Studio", @"Be & D", @"Belle by Sigerson Morrison", @"Bettye Muller ", @"Beverly Feldman", @"Botkier", @"Bourne", @"Bottega Veneta", @"Brian Atwood", @"Burberry", @"Burberry Prorsum", @"Camilla Skovgaard", @"Candela", @"Carlos Falchi", @"Casadei ", @"Chie Mihara", @"Chloe", @"Christian Louboutin", @"Claudio Merazzi", @"Coach", @"Cole Haan", @"Comme des Garcons", @"Costume National", @"Cynthis Vincent", @"Delman ", @"Devi Kroell", @"Derek Lam", @"Diane von Furstenberg", @"Dior", @"Dolce & Gabbana", @"Dolce Vita", @"Donald J Pliner ", @"Donna Karan", @"Elie Tahari ", @"Elizabeth and James", @"Emilio Pucci", @"Emma Hope", @"Eric Javits", @"Fendi", @"Ferragamo ", @"Foley & Corinna", @"Frye ", @"Furla", @"Giuseppe Zanotti", @"Givenchy", @"Gucci", @"Halston Heritage", @"H by Hudson", @"Hobo International", @"House of Harlow 1960", @"Hunter", @"Jack Rogers", @"Jean Paul ", @"Jerome C. Rousseau", @"Jil Sander", @"Jimmy Choo", @"Joan & David", @"Joie", @"Jonathan Kelsey", @"Judith Leiber", @"Juicy Couture", @"Junya Watanabe", @"Kate Spade", @"Kooba", @"Kork-Ease ", @"Kors Michael Kors", @"L.A.M.B.", @"LD Tuttle", @"Le Silla", @"Lanvin", @"Lilly Pulitzer", @"Linea Pelle", @"Lockheart", @"Loeffler Randall", @"Longchamp", @"Luciano Padovan", @"Maison Martin Margiela", @"Maison Martin Margiela MM6", @"MANITOBAH MUKLUKS ", @"MANOLO BLAHNIK ", @"Marc by Marc Jacobs", @"Marc Jacobs", @"Marina Rinaldi", @"MATT BERNSON ", @"Max Kibardin", @"MCM", @"Melissa", @"Michael Kors", @"MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS", @"Milly", @"Miu Miu", @"Miss Sixty", @"Missoni", @"Modern Vintage", @"Moschino", @"Moschino Cheap and Chic", @"Nancy Gonzalez", @"Narcisco Rodriguez", @"Nina Ricci", @"Nicholas Kirkwood", @"Olivia Harris", @"Opening Ceremony", @"Oscar de la Renta", @"PATRICIA GREEN ", @"Pedro Garcia ", @"Philosophy by Alberta Ferretti", @"Pollini", @"Prada", @"Proenza Schouler", @"Pura Lopez",@"Rachel Comey ", @"Rag & Bone", @"Ralph Lauren", @"Rebecca Minkoff", @"Rene Caovilla ", @"Repetto", @"Robert Clergerie ", @"Rock & Republic", @"Rosegold", @"Rupert Sanderson", @"Salvatore Ferragamo", @"SAM EDELMAN ", @"Scorah Pattulo", @"See by Chloe", @"7 for all mankind ", @"Sergio Rossi", @"Sigerson Morrison", @"Stella McCartney ", @"Stephane Verdino", @"Steve Madden", @"Storksak", @"Stuart Weitzman", @"Studio Pollini", @"Taryn Rose", @"Thakoon", @"Theory", @"Tracy Reese", @"Tod's", @"TOMS ", @"Tory Burch", @"UGG Australia", @"Valentino", @"Vera Wang Lavender Label", @"Versace", @"Via Spiga", @"Vince Camuto", @"Yves Saint Laurent", @"Zac Posen", @"Zagliani", @"-", nil];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:designerArray forKey:@"designerArray"];

    shoeStyles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"Ankle Strap", @"Ballet Flat", @"Boot", @"Bootie", @"Buckle Strap", @"Caged", @"Cowboy Boot", @"D'Orsay", @"Espadrille", @"Flat", @"Flat Sandal", @"Lace Up Boot",@"Mary Jane", @"Mid Calf Boot", @"Open Toe Flat", @"Open Toe Pump", @"Platform", @"Strappy Sandal", @"Thigh High Boot", @"Rain Boot", @"Sling Back", @"T-Strap", @"-", nil];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:shoeStyles forKey:@"shoeStyles"];
```

Comment: You might want to consider storing your designer and shoe style arrays as plist files rather than hardcoding them into your program.

Comment: Why?  They are editable and they get assigned to NSUserDefaults fine.  I don't know why people use plists all the time...

Comment: The reason why people often prefer using a plist instead of hardcoding the arrays in is to avoid potential breakages in code if you ever need to change them, or if you ever want to change the source you can easily do an HTTP get to grab the plist from somewhere and easily import it.

Comment: "HTTP get to grab the plist" - Where do you find plists for use?  I think the formatting of the plist is a pain.  I'd much rather format a comma separated array.

Comment: @Bryan, if by "editable" you mean having to recompile the application for every change, then yeah, that is editable. Having the static data of your application in separate files (I suggested plists because of their compatibility with Cocoa) makes it easier to maintain in the long run. [Hard-coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard-coding) is typically considered an anti-pattern.

Comment: @Bryan, also, don't get me wrong, it was only a suggestion to use plists, not a criticism.

Comment: By editable, I mean I have the array bound the rows of a table.  Each row can be edited and new rows can be added to the table - all bound to the NSUserDefaults array.  I have a ton of experience with xml and plists.  I see the plist as unnecessary and bloated in most cases.

Comment: @Bryan: Store them as binary plists if you think they're too bloated. In any case, serialised static data in a separate file decouples it from your code (where it doesn't really belong). Serialise and deserialise however you want, the easiest route is probably with plists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you set the default to an NSMutableArray and then if you change the mutable array outside of the defaults, you lose the changes?

If so, the defaults probably haven't noticed that you have changed the array.  You need to create a new array and send `-setObject:forKey:` again (or use the same mutable array and send `-setObject:forKey:`).

By the way, the docs say you can only pass an NSArray.  That doesn't mean you can't pass NSMutableArray but you need to keep to the spirit of the contract and not change the array you pass in.

Comment: I am not changing the mutable array outside of defaults.  The defaults get changed and when I log the contents of NSUserDefaults I see the changes, but when I exit and relaunch the application the changes do not stick.  Also, NSMutableArrays are set and retrieved fine.

Comment: @Bryan: One thing I forgot to mention is you don't need to do the first run thing.  You should just use `-registerDefaults:` some time during app start up and then just change things when you need to. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Tasks/UsingDefaults.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000719-97292

Answer (score 1):

When are you calling saveUserDefaults?

I would also recommend only calling [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] once inside a method. Just keep a pointer to the object and use it again and again, like so:

`NSMutableArray *designerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"Alberta Ferretti" ...;`

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:designerArray forKey:@"designerArray"];
[defaults synchronize];

I used the above code with your designer array and it worked for me.

Comment: That does not do anything.   The problem is I print out the defaults before I exit the app and the values are correct (changed). But when I exit and relaunch the app, the values remain the same.

Comment: The above code does work for me. Since the values in your app look correct before exiting but don't persist for the next launch that implies that you aren't committing the changes. When are you calling saveUserDefaults()?

Comment: Kenny - Interestingly by adding this to saveUserDefaults it worked: [standardDefaults setObject:[standardDefaults objectForKey:@"designerArray"] forKey:@"designerArray"];

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.  I pretty much had to reassign the array to itself.

```
[standardDefaults setObject:[standardDefaults objectForKey:@"designerArray"] forKey:@"designerArray"];
```