# How can i save NSArray of MPMediaPlaylist to NSUserDefaults

Tags: nsarray

I try to save my NSArray of MPMediaPlaylist

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.playlistArray forKey:@"playlist"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

But i have error

```
-[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value '(
    "<MPConcreteMediaPlaylist: 0x1e8614a0>"
)' of class '__NSArrayM'.  Note that dictionaries and arrays in property lists must also contain only property values.
2013-06-26 20:06:44.393 Fitness[5326:907] (
    "<MPConcreteMediaPlaylist: 0x1e8614a0>"
)
```

So how can i resolve this problems?

Thanks you guy

Answer (score 0):

Because self.playlistArray is NSMutableArray.So you got this error. Have a look at following links.

[Saving a NSMutableArray using NSUserDefaults not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444131/saving-a-nsmutablearray-using-nsuserdefaults-not-working)

[NSUserDefaults NSMutable Array Not Saving Between Sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127306/nsuserdefaults-nsmutable-array-not-saving-between-sessions)

[insert object in an NSMutableArray saved with NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346395/insert-object-in-an-nsmutablearray-saved-with-nsuserdefaults)